# Crawling the contents from multiple pages

Tags: python, web-crawler

I would like to do crawling the Coursera Reviews(course reviews) from the 1~5 pages. (yellow part of the picture)
So I tried to write a code...but I had difficulty progressing...
Please help me~~~

[image]

```
pip install selenium

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
from selenium import webdriver

driver=webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe')

bs_url= "https://www.consumeraffairs.com"
plus = '/education/online-courses/coursera.html?page=#scroll_to_reviews=true'
driver.get(bs_url)]

pip install bs4

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains 

for z in range(5):  
    driver.get(bs_url+plus+str(z+1))
    soup= BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
    res_lis=soup.find_all('div',class="rvw-bd")
```

Comment: Hi @Genie , if you're referring to functions in some programming language, consider adding the tag of that language (and the package that you're using) to your question

Comment: supply webpage, you will have to get source of web page and find these elements on the bottom and for loop each element, alternatively you could see where page variable in your URL and just change that variable and loop thru that accessing every page that way

Comment: I edit my question more detailed. Could you help me to solve the problem?